# How can i fix my fatal git error?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I just wanted to commit my changes to my local git, when i noticed that the Local Changes window was missing all the changes of the past 3 hours, and was just showing the following error message:

[image: Error message in IntelliJ IDEA]

I haven't changed anything in my setup compared to the last 50 commits. I had this problem 2 months ago already and wasn't able to fix it back then either, but I also noticed it fairly quickly and just pulled again and repeated the changes, but this time its not that easy.

How can I fix this problem, and restore the detected changes again, to stage them for a commit? In the files the changes are still there, but whatever I do, it's not getting tracked anymore.

**EDIT:** Hitting the refresh button in the local changes window in IntelliJ fixed it. Problem solved.

Comment: As the error says, the permission of `.git/file` refused to be open by git. Maybe try fix the permission of the file for your current user?

Comment: As I said, nothing was changed. It's just some git hickup I seem to have randomly. I just noticed though, that there is a manually refresh button for the local changes in intelliJ and everything seems to be back now. Going to close the question again now, if no problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see a permission denied on Windows when a process (here `git.exe ls-file`) tries to access a file, it is possible that file is preempted by another process.

When you see that error message, open a [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and look for (CTRL+F) the filename, to see if another process uses it.